# Is there a general formula to generate all numbers with a given binary / Hamming weight?

Tags: combinatorics, binary

It's easy to generate numbers that have one non-zero digit in their binary representation, and it's not much harder to generate numbers with two non-zero digits. It rapidly seems to become more difficult, though. Is there a general formula that will let me generate all numbers of all lengths with (say) 7 non-zero digits, starting with 1111111 and continuing indefinitely?

If there isn't a general formula, is there a standard algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean "of a given digit length" or "as an infinite sequence"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an algorithm: how standard it is I couldn't tell you, but it's well enough known that I learnt it as an undergrad in computer science. It's due to Bill Gosper and it transforms a number into the next largest number with the same Hamming weight using (twos complement) arithmetic and bitwise operations. Input `val`, output `next`, code (with suitable types) is valid in most languages related to C, although some may need `>>>` instead of `>>` for right shift without sign extension:

```
c = val & -val;
r = val + c;
next = (((r^val) >> 2) / c) | r;
```

`c` is the least power of 2 in the binary representation of `val`: this relies on twos complement, since to negate an integer you invert its bits and add 1.

`val + c` causes carries to ripple through the continuous set bits from `c` up until a 1 is carried into a 0.

`r ^ val` therefore gives a value equal to twice the value of the lowest continuous block of set bits in `val`. Shifting right 2 is equivalent to division by 4, and then dividing also by `c` causes the bottom bit in `r ^ val` to be lost to a flooring operation. Since `r` has kept one carry bit, the final Hamming weight of `next` will therefore be the same as in `val`, and if this explanation is clear enough then it should be obvious that it's the lexicographically next value with that property.

Comment: There is a separate good discussion in English about the bit-shifting / manipulation being achieved by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573497/binary-number-having-same-number-of-0s-and-1s

Comment: Is there an algorithm to find the mth number in faster than O(m) time?

Comment: Sharing in case it helps with understanding: $c$ is a power of $2$ and since $c$ is a power of $2$, say $2^n$, division by $c$ is equivalent to right shifting by $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate all numbers whose binary representation has exactly $k$ non-zero digits, and is at most $n$ digits long, the following procedure works: Let $S = \{0, 1, 2, \dotsc, n-1\}$. For all $T \in S$ where $|T| = k$, the number $\sum_{t \in T} 2^t$ has exactly $k$ non-zero digits, and further they are all unique. Assuming you are using a computer, it is easy for computers to iterate over all such subsets of $S$.

If you want to generate all numbers whose binary representation has exactly $k$ non-zero digits regardless of total length, the following procedure works: The first number is $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^k$. After that, let $S = \{0, 1, 2, \dotsc, k-1\}$. Iterate a variable $x$ starting from $k$ and continuing upwards indefinitely. For each value of $x$, choose a subset of $T$ such that $|T| = k-1$ and generate a number as described above. To this number add $2^x$. This gives you unique numbers with exactly $k$ non-zero digits and goes on forever.

Comment: shouldn't "digits" here be replaced with "bits"?

Comment: "Assuming you are using a computer, it is easy for computers to iterate over all such subsets of S." Wait, that doesn't answer the question at all?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following to help myself and others visualize Peter Taylor's great answer. Hope it helps!

---

Rename $val$ to $a$.
Let $n' = m+n+1$. ($m$ and $n$ are defined shortly)

Visually break the binary representation of $a$ from right (lsb) to left (MSB) into

- `ntz`: a string of $n$ trailing zeros ($n$ can be $0$)
- `lssb`: the rightmost (least significant) set bit, occurring at position $n$
- `mo`: a string of $m$ ones immediately to the left of `lssb` ($m$ can be $0$)
- `zmo`: the zero immediately to the left of `mo`, occurring at position $n' = m+n+1$
- `pre`: a prefix $i$

$$
a\!:\boxed{\qquad i \qquad} \underset{n'}{\boxed{0}} \overbrace{\boxed{1 ... 1}}^{m \geq 0} \underset{n}{\boxed{1}} \overbrace{\boxed{0 ... 0}}^{n \geq 0}
$$

The *Hamming weight* of $a$, denoted $H(a)$, is $H(i)+m+1$.

Now we can visualize the operations

```
c = a & -a
r = a + c`
next = (((r^a) >> 2) / c) | r;
```

as shown further below. But first:

- Let $q$ be the negation of $p$, i.e. $p$ with its bits flipped.
- Note that $c$ is a power of $2$ -- specifically, the visualization will show that $c = 2^n$. Furthermore, note that division by $2^n$ is equivalent to right shifting by $n$, so division by $c$ is the same as right shifting by $n$. Thus `((r^a) >> 2) / c` is equivalent to `(r^a) >> (2+n)`.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{a}:\ &&\boxed{\qquad i \qquad} \overset{n'}{\boxed{0}} \overbrace{\boxed{1 ... 1}}^{m \geq 0} \overset{n}{\boxed{1}} \overbrace{\boxed{0 ... 0}}^{n \geq 0}\\
\text{-a}:\ &&\boxed{\qquad i \qquad} \boxed{1} \boxed{0 ... 0} \boxed{1} \boxed{0 ... 0}\\
\text{c = a & -a}:\ &&\boxed{\qquad 0 \qquad} \boxed{0} \boxed{0 ... 0} \boxed{1} \boxed{0 ... 0}\\
\text{r = a + c}:\ &&\boxed{\qquad i \qquad} \boxed{1} \boxed{0 ... 0} \boxed{0} \boxed{0 ... 0}\\
\text{r ^ a}:\ &&\boxed{\qquad 0 \qquad} \boxed{1} \boxed{1 ... 1} \boxed{1} \boxed{0 ... 0}\\
\text{b = (r ^ a) >> (2+n)}:\ &&\overbrace{\boxed{1 ... 1}}^{m \geq 0}\\
\text{next = b | r}:\ &&\boxed{\qquad i \qquad} \overset{n'}{\boxed{1}} \overbrace{\boxed{0 ... 0}}^{n \geq 0} \overset{m}{\boxed{0}} \overbrace{\boxed{1 ... 1}}^{m \geq 0}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Where in the last line of the visualization, we note that $n' = m+n+1 > m$ to further note that all the $1$s of $b$ are to the right of the rightmost $1$ of $r$, thus $H(\text{b | r}) = H(b) + H(r) = m + H(i) + 1$ and thus $H(next) = H(a)$. Further reasoning shows that $\text{next}$ is lexicographically the next number with the same *Hamming weight* as $a$.

---

Note: I originally wrote this in StackEdit, where the alignment was much better.